# vim: where is the autocompletion preview window for ctags generated tags?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

The documentation for the "completeopt" options says:

```
...
A comma separated list of options for Insert mode completion
|ins-completion|.  The supported values are:
...
preview  Show extra information about the currently selected
         completion in the preview window.  Only works in
         combination with "menu" or "menuone".
```

For me this sounds that if "menu" and "preview" is set, you always get a preview window for the current autocompleted item, so for a ctags tag I expected to see a preview of the file, where the item is defined (the same as I would press CTRL-W-} on a tag under the cursor).
But it seems this preview window is only available for omni-completion, if the set omnifunc supports it. How could I also get a preview window for autocompleted tags?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in completions don't have much additional stuff to show, so this feature is only available for custom completions (as you'd correctly assumed), namely via the `info` attribute in the returned completion items, see `:help complete-items`.

If you really would like additional information about tags (but there isn't much, see `:help tags-file-format`), you'd have to write a custom completion (sourced from `taglist()`) and populate the mentioned `info` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from perfect but you can `set showfulltag` to get more information for each suggestion.

Without `set showfulltag`:

[image: set noshowfulltag]

With `set showfulltag`:

[image: set showfulltag]

As you can see, the completion menu becomes a little crowded and you must skip entries but well…

Using the preview window would be so much nicer.

See `:help 'showfulltag'`.

Comment: OK, thanks so far. I was wondering if I missed an option. Something like `showtagpreview` or so. I know that some completion items have not much information to preview, but I expected that if an item has no implemented "info", that the source code of the item definition is previewed then.
The documentation should mention that the preview is only for custom completion. I do not want to write one for this. It is Ok for now to complete first and press CTRL-W_} afterward.
Maybe I can convince the author of neocomplete to implement this.

Thanks!